# Averaging percentages of enum-based subjects in a MYSQL table

Tags: mysql

I have a MYSQL table where each row contain a subject (from an enum selection) and percentages of a student's ability on the subject(s).  I'm trying to get an average of a student's  percentages in that table. I've been trying things like:

```
SELECT sid, level, AVG(Percent) FROM 'PROGalphabet' group by (select DISTINCT level from PROGalphabet) where sid = 45
```

which isn't working. (Sorry that it looks like a code salad.)
Here is a snippet of the table:

```
  CREATE TABLE 'PROGalphabet' (
  'rid' int(24) NOT NULL,
  'sid' int(4) NOT NULL,
  'date' timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  'level' enum('Alphabet in Order','Point ABCs randomly','Tell ABCs randomly','knows phonics','starts reading') NOT NULL,
  'Percent' tinyint(3) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
INSERT INTO 'PROGalphabet' ('rid', 'sid', 'date', 'level', 'Percent') VALUES
(36, 45, '2019-01-20 15:51:42', 'Alphabet in Order', 61),
(37, 45, '2019-01-20 15:52:00', 'Alphabet in Order', 77),
(38, 45, '2019-01-20 15:57:11', 'Alphabet in Order', 85),
(51, 45, '2019-01-21 13:27:10', 'Alphabet in Order', 80),
(52, 45, '2019-01-21 13:37:27', 'Alphabet in Order', 67),
(54, 45, '2019-01-23 01:30:41', 'Alphabet in Order', 37),
(77, 45, '2019-01-29 02:10:57', 'Point ABCs randomly', 37),
(78, 45, '2019-01-29 02:10:59', 'Point ABCs randomly', 100),
(79, 45, '2018-12-12 06:46:22', 'starts reading', 1),
(80, 45, '2019-01-30 06:46:25', 'starts reading', 26),
(91, 45, '2019-04-11 16:00:00', 'starts reading', 60);

ALTER TABLE 'PROGalphabet'
  ADD PRIMARY KEY ('rid'),
  ADD KEY 'sid' ('sid');

ALTER TABLE 'PROGalphabet'
  MODIFY 'rid' int(24) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=161;
COMMIT;
```

I have been helped with this solution. However, if all values in 'level' are not present for a particular 'sid' the average for the query will be off. The option is to 'zero' all 'level' values for all 'sid's that do not have an entry.

```
SELECT sid, ROUND(AVG(averagepercent),1) AS 'Overall Average %'
FROM
(
    SELECT sid, LEVEL, AVG(Percent) AS 'averagepercent'
    FROM `PROGalphabet`  p2 WHERE sid = 45
    GROUP BY sid, LEVEL
) p1
GROUP BY sid
```

Is there a way to insert (SELECT DISTINCT level from PROGalphabet) into the above query in order to account for all possible 'level' values? This would bring a much more accurate result.

Comment: show the sample result for your sample data by editing the question. Don't forget the  statistical wrongness  of averaging percentages.

Comment: `... GROUP BY level WHERE ...` would do.

Comment: Do you need average progress on level in which only the last student answer is taken into account?

Comment: Anything in inverted commas is a 'string'

Comment: Also (and I see this again and again these days) the number in parentheses following an INT declaration is almost entirely meaningless and is probably best omitted.

Comment: Well, I apologize for the 'INT' inundation; the snippet was exported from PHPmyAdmin.

Comment: RusArtM, something like that.  in the beginning, I was trying sort on date desc, limit 1, but I could only pull that off with a query based on just one of the items in level, I got lost on getting all latest (1) percentages and then averaging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
SELECT sid, COUNT(ttl) level_count, SUM(ttl) perc_sum, 
       SUM(ttl)/5 average_required, AVG(ttl) average_so_far 
FROM (
 SELECT sid,level, AVG(percent) ttl 
 FROM PROGalphabet 
 GROUP BY sid,level
) t 
GROUP BY sid
```

The inner `SELECT` will calculate the average for each level any student has received results for, then these averages will be summed up in the outer `SELECT` and divided by the total number of *required* levels (here: 5) to form the column `average_required`. The column `level_count` informs you about the number of the so far available level results for each student, so you can easily find those cases where a student has not yet got results for all levels.

The last column `average_so_far` calculates the average of all so far achieved level results (without penalising for missing levels) and is a "fairer" way of looking at the student's abilities so far.

You will find a little demo here: https://rextester.com/ZYV82280

With an extended sample data set like this

```
    sid level   percent
1   45  Alphabet in Order   61
2   45  Alphabet in Order   77
3   45  Alphabet in Order   85
4   45  Alphabet in Order   80
5   45  Alphabet in Order   67
6   45  Alphabet in Order   37
7   45  Point ABCs randomly 37
8   45  Point ABCs randomly 100
9   45  starts reading  1
10  45  starts reading  26
11  45  starts reading  60
12  5   Tell ABCs randomly  61
13  5   Alphabet in Order   77
14  5   Alphabet in Order   85
15  5   Alphabet in Order   80
16  5   Alphabet in Order   67
17  5   Alphabet in Order   57
18  5   Point ABCs randomly 67
19  5   Point ABCs randomly 80
20  5   knows phonics   75
21  5   starts reading  26
22  5   starts reading  60
```

you will get the following result:

```
    sid level_count perc_sum    average_required    average_so_far
1     5           5 325.7000         65.14000000       65.14000000
2    45           3 165.3333         33.06666000       55.11110000
```